# Excel Time Hours:Minutes to Minutes

Tags: excel, time, type-conversion, formula, minute

I have some information that I copy/paste from a text file.  These come across in such a fashion that I have to do a "Text to Column", which does leave the time neatly in their own column in the format of H:MM.  I can use the formula =C2*60*24 (because C2 is where the first time I need to convert is placed, followed by the next time in C3, etc.).  That formula works except for values under 1 hour.  For example, if I have a cell that says :22 (for 22 minutes), the formula cell results are "#VALUE!"???  Anyone have a solution or a fix to try?

Comment: That's interesting.  It's because :22 is not a valid time.  There NEEDS to be an hour there in order for it to resolve.  You may have to come up with some other formula that uses 22/60ths for its base.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your solution completely?  How would I do that b/c every type of math I try on that cell just gives me a "#VALUE!" as a result?  So how would I do it as a base of 22/60?  And wouldn't that only work on times of 22 minutes?

Comment: This worked to get :22 as time, then I could use the =C2*60*24 to get the minutes:
=IF(LEFT(C2)=":",CONCATENATE(0,C2), C2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you prefix with a zero and use the [TIMEVALUE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIMEVALUE-function-0B615C12-33D8-4431-BF3D-F3EB6D186645) function?

```
=TIMEVALUE(0&C2)*60*24
```

Optionally, only prefix with the zero if there is a leading colon.

```
=TIMEVALUE(IF(LEFT(C2, 1)=":", 0, "")&C2)*60*24
```

Comment: Thank you! I had just discovered someone saying to use a "LEFT" function. :) Though the solution you have didn't work for me. This worked to get :22 as time, then I could use the =C2*60*24 to get the mintues:

=IF(LEFT(C2)=":",CONCATENATE(0,C2), C2)